# Should I declare my property as from type Class or Interface?

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I started to write in Typescript.
Should I declare my class properties as from type of interface or of a a specific class (that implements that specific interface)?

```
    import { ITable, Table } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb";
    import { Construct } from "constructs";
    
    export class Database extends Construct {

       public readonly usersTable: Table; // <======== should it be Table(class) or ITable(interface)

       constructor(scope, id) {
           super(scope, id);
           this.usersTable = this.createUsersTable();
       }

       private createUsersTable(): Table { // <======== should it be Table(class) or ITable(interface)
          // some implementation
          ...
 
          return usersTable;
  
       } 
    }
```

What is the better practice?

Answer (score 0):

the Interfaces in CDK are for type checking and for Construct building.

When declaring the object, you have to ask yourself - Is this going to HAVE to be a Table or can it be a Table Like Object? At this point in time there is only one Table like Resource - a Table.

There are some things that have multiple Resources that are some what interchangeable - types of IAM Policies for instance. But even so, the code in the CDK that accepts a policy already accepts an interface.

Unless you are building your own custom Construct objects, then I would stay away from using the Interfaces. It causes confusion, and in Typescript may not even work properly in some cases I believe (not 100% certain, Typescript is not my strength)

Its best to use Interfaces when designing properties/parameters that take a particular type but can take any version of that type. For just straight up object declaration, the Type is better as its *always* better to be exact and specific than general.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why you might prefer interfaces over concrete classes is to enable your construct to work with imported resources, which usually produce an interface (such as [fromTableArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_dynamodb.Table.html#static-fromwbrtablewbrarnscope-id-tablearn) method). If you know that you or anyone else using your construct won’t be using imported resources, then I can’t think of a good reason to use interfaces, because using interfaces often limits your access to some properties. For example Lambda’s IFunction interface doesn’t have timeout property exposed, while Function has.

Answer (score -1):

It is always better to use interfaces. However some functions are not available using interfaces in CDK. I use interfaces on constructs input and public methods. For private properties / methods I use interface by default and I change it rarely to concrete type if needed.

Comment: can you explain why it is better to use interfaces rather than concrete type?

Comment: @MoysheZuchmir you can use imported resources with interfaces e.g. Vpc.fromVpcAttributes plus you are open for future options